# What is the right way to populate a dropdown from MySql?

Tags: plugins, php, widgets

I am having a heck of a time solving this problem. Please help me find the right way to do this.
I am creating a widget that has a dropdown populated with data from custom table;
This is the form code:

```
public function form($instance) {
       global $event;
       global $events;       
       $events = new WP_Query( "SELECT id, event FROM mo_Event");
     ?>     
    <select class="dropdown" id="mydropdown" name="mydropdown" title="My Dropdown">
    <?php
    foreach ($events as $event) { ?> 
      <option value="' . <?php $event . '">' . $event . '?> </option>';
    }?>
  </select>
  }
```

This line:
      `<option value="' . <?php $event . '">' . $event . '?> </option>'`;
  is getting "PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion"
  And "PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Tax_Query could not be converted to string "
  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `get_results()` instead of `WP_Query`.

I have made changes in your code and tested at my end and it is working for me. I have also save that value using `update()` function of widget. You can take reference from below code.

```
  public function form( $instance ) {

    if ( isset( $instance[ 'mydropdown' ] ) )
    $selectedvalue = $instance[ 'mydropdown' ];
    else
    $selectedvalue = __( '', 'text-domain' );

    global $event;
    global $events;       
    global $wpdb;  

     $events = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id, event FROM mo_Event",ARRAY_A);
       ?>     
      <select class="dropdown" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'mydropdown' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'mydropdown' ); ?>" title="My Dropdown">
      <?php
      foreach ($events as $event) {
      $selected = ($event->id == $selectedvalue) ? 'selected' : '';  
        echo '<option value="'.$event->id.'" '.$selected.'>'.$event->event.'</option>';
      }
      ?>
      </select>
      <?php
  }

  public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['mydropdown'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['mydropdown'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['mydropdown'] ) : '';
    return $instance;
  }
```

Comment: I need to make a long response with code snippets. How can I do that?